# need to create and read and modify xml files with NSIS

Tags: xml, installation, nsis

I am trying to create new xml file and modify existing files.

I tried three different plugins:
[XML plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/XML_plug-in), [NsisXML plug-in (by Joel)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisXML_plug-in_%28by_Joel%29) and [NsisXML plug-in (by Wizou)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisXML_plug-in_%28by_Wizou%29).

I ran their samples, both NsisXML plug-ins crashed and the first one (XML Plugin) did nothing.. I can't really understand how to work with the first plugin because the sample code is one big mess. I dont know if I'm using the right plug-ins or not.

I need it in order to write into an xml file the selected language so I can use it later in the program.

So how would I do this?

(and if I can modify file I added to the installer [before the installer release it]).

Thanks.

EDIT:
so, I solved all my problems and I want to tell how I solved everything.
I used the NsisXML plugin by Wizou, there are 2 dll files - 1 for ANSI version and the second for Unicode version. I used the unicode version of the xml inside ansi version of NSIS. so I downloaded the unicode version (support more languages) and inorder to modify file that in the installer, I just waited the installer to release the file and then opened the file and modified him.

one more thing - I wrote to the xml what language the user selected so I'll use it in the program - $(^Language) holds the string of language name $language holds the language ID.

Comment: Are you using the unicode version of nsis?

Comment: Unicode and Portable, I compiled it in ANSI one and it worked.. what can I do? I need 4 languages that are in Unicode but not in ANSI

Comment: what do you from the last line you added in the bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this post helps:
http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=1779053&postcount=22

[List of functions and install instructions are here.](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisXML_plug-in_%28by_Joel%29)